# How the application upgrade works in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am planning to post an application for iPhone in iTunes Store. Soon I am gonna provide an upgrade for it. But later to current version. I want to know how the upgrade system works in iPhone. Like does it replaces the whole application and reinstall it deleteing the previous database or it adds the new version keeping the database and all the same.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrades replace the app bundle, but anything else in your sandbox (like the Documents folder, caches, preferences, etc) are preserved in place.

Comment: I was on the way to post the same question, but the problem for me is that I save a database and some downloaded images inside the application Documents folder and from some reasons the images are deleted after update. Is that possible or I am just wrong about it.   I had complains about users not seeing the downloaded image after application update, but the lists were correctly populated which means that the datatbase is still there and in good shape.